# Views multi field exposed free-text filter/search

Tags: views

I have a view displaying some course listings. I want to enable a free-text search on some of the fields. Some of these fields will be a term-reference type, and some will be text fields.

What's the best way to enable this type of search functionality? I've stumbled upon this: http://drupal.org/project/search_api but wanted someone else's opinion.

Answer (score 3):

You could do that without the help of the search filters.

On my Drupal instance I have Views 7.x-3.7 there is a filter `Global: Combine fields filter (exposed)` This lets me add multiple fields and then enables users to `search on selected fields` using a single filter.

Comment: This works. And just a note, you would probably want to change the operator from "is equal to" to "contains any word"

Comment: I tried this but text box is not appeared.Is there any step to add filter box

Comment: I forgot to change advance setting 'use ajax' to 'Yes'

Comment: It seems this only accepts fields that are already added in the "Fields" configuration section of the views display.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable the core Search module, and then wait for the site to be fully indexed, you can add the views filter:

```
Search: Search Terms
The terms to search for.
```

When this filter is exposed, it will provide a free-text search box which filters items in the view by any of their indexed keywords.

Comment: This isn't showing up as an option for me. I only see "Global: Combine fields filter" when I try to find a "search" filter

Answer (score 0):

For the "Search: Search Terms", you also have to enable "Use AJAX" under Advanced -> OTHER in your view for the searchbox to be visible.